# Symfony 2 FOSUSER issue with is_granted in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'am experiencing an issue with is_granted('') function in twig.
My current user has the following roles : `['ROLE_USER','ROLE_FOOBAR']`, checked from the symfony profiler.

With this code : the admin link is printed (KO) :

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_BACKOFFICE') or is_granted('ROLE_SYSTEM') %}
<li>
    <a href="{{ path('sonata_admin_dashboard') }}">
       ADMIN
    </a>
</li>
{% endif %}
```

With this code : the admin link is NOT printed (OK) :

```
{% if app.user.hasRole('ROLE_BACKOFFICE') or  app.user.hasRole('ROLE_SYSTEM') %}
<li>
    <a href="{{ path('sonata_admin_dashboard') }}">
       ADMIN
    </a>
</li>
{% endif %}
```

I don't understand why the link is printed with is_granted ?
My role hierarchy seems ok, what's wrong with that code ?

If you look at vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Model/User.php, it explains that the hasRole must not be used in this context :

```
  /**
     * Never use this to check if this user has access to anything!
     *
     * Use the SecurityContext, or an implementation of AccessDecisionManager
     * instead, e.g.
     *
     *         $securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER');
     *
     * @param string $role
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->getRoles(), true);
    }
```

Here is a snippet of my role hierarchy from security.yml :

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_FOOBAR:         ROLE_USER
...
    ROLE_ADMIN:         [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MANAGER]
```

Comment: Can we see your role hierarchy please ?

Comment: go to profiler and then security part. you can see which user is logged in and what role he has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem : 
The problem came from an error inside a voter. I change this snippet :

```
     if ($object != null && !$this->supportsClass(get_class($object))) {
         return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
     }
```

to :

```
 if (!$this->supportsClass(get_class($object))) {
        return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }
```

Now, everything is fine, again. just lost my day ! I hope this could help.